# How can i upload my debug apk to playStore?

Tags: android, apk, react-native, in-app-billing

I need to test InAppBilling with my debuggable apk. I tried to sign my debug.apk and upload it, unfortunately it doesn´t work. This is what i have done:

Generate Keystore:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias debug_app -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

Sign APK:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore debug.keystore app-debug.apk debug_app
(Actually i never know to use aligned or unaligend)
```

Then i ZipAlign it:

```
zipalign -f -v 4 SomeName.apk  app-debug.apk
```

Now when i do this and install it via:

```
adb install SomeName.apk
```

I get a **Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]**

Any ideas? The next step would be to put the signed app-debug.apk to the play Store and test it via Alpha/Beta-Test. I am using ReactNative to build my Android App.

Answer (score 3):

Is that debug.keystore the auto-generated debug keystore?

If it is, you can't. You have to generate a keystore that is not a debug one to be able to upload it.

If you have one that is not a debug one, check Signing Your App Manually section [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: i generated by my self: keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias debug_app -keyalg RSA -validity 10000